# Next.js app folder: is there some "entry point"? A direct replacement for _app.tsx and _document.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Previously I had a custom `_app.tsx` that did some bootstrapping for my application:
`useEffect(() => void defineCustomElements(), []);` It loaded custom elements/web components and made sure they can be hydrated.

Where should I put this effect now with the app router that 1. doesn't have a "global" `_app.tsx` and secondly is "server component first"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the [Upgrade Guide](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/upgrade-guide) page, they say *"`pages/_app.js` and `pages/_document.js` have been replaced with a single `app/layout.js` root layout"*.

In your case where you need client interactions in the layout, you could do as below, for example, using a separate client component that you import in the layout:

```js
// DefineCustomElements.js

"use client";

export default function DefineCustomElements() {
  useEffect(() => defineCustomElements(), []);

  return <></>;
}
```

```js
// app/layout.js

import DefineCustomElements from "./DefineCustomElements";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <DefineCustomElements />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: It is not possible for the root layout to be a client component. The docs say "The root layout is a Server Component by default and can not be set to a Client Component." [ref](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#root-layout-required)