# How to configure Material UI with Next.js new experimental `app/` directory

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

The official docs provide an example [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/HEAD/examples/material-next-ts) for `material-next-ts`. I couldn't configure that in the new experimental `app/` directory.
What is the equivalent file of `_app.ts` or `_document.ts` in new `app/` directory ?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75951134/next-js-app-folder-is-there-some-entry-point-a-direct-replacement-for-app-t?

Comment: Well, No It doesn't I tried setting the MUI but it doesn't work. I can't just place the contents in `layout.ts` file. so I still have problem setting it up with MUI server components

Comment: Going through same phase. I would recommend going back to page directory file system in nextjs as it will provide you with both server side css and it will be easy to work with as it has a lot of community support compared to app directory which is new.

Comment: There is an extensive thread on this on the MUI github page: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/34898

So far, it still seems as though using MUI with the App directory structure in Next 13 requires quite a bit of manual intervention. But this would be the thread to follow.

Answer (score 0):

pages/_app.js and pages/_document.js have been replaced with a single app/layout.js root layout.
More about the topic: [migrating-from-pages-to-app](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#migrating-from-pages-to-app)

Material UI was indeed difficult to implement because these client and server-side components, so outcome was a little over complicated when combining several templates and sources. Anyways feel free to browse template repo and additional sources linked in bottom of Readme.
[nextjs-storybook-mui-app-dir-template](https://github.com/AkiKurvinen/nextjs-storybook-mui-app-dir-template)