# Nextjs 13 library initialization in experimental app directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks

What is the way to initialise libraries like LogRocket after the new NextJS 13 came out with the experimental `app` directory? For example, I used to initialise it using the `useEffect` script inside the `_app.tsx` file like so:

```
import LogRocket from 'logrocket';

useEffect(() => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    LogRocket.init(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_LOGROCKET_APP_ID);
}, []);
```

Now, NextJS complains the `useEffect` hook can not be called on a server-side component, as I am trying to run this code from the `layout.tsx`. What is the new way to inject scripts like this globally?

Comment: Check my question and the respective answer, it works perfectly fine.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75951134/next-js-app-folder-is-there-some-entry-point-a-direct-replacement-for-app-t

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have installed the library using `npm install logrocket`.

You only need to return it for all the pages using return statement.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      LogRocket.init(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_LOGROCKET_APP_ID);
    }
  }, []);

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
```

Make sure the `useEffect` should be inside the function.
This will work for you.

Comment: Add init to all pages? What a bad advise Xd. Any further solutions like use `use strict` for the `layout` page, at least?