# Using web components in React sever components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stenciljs, react-server-components

Prior the /app router and default server components in Next.js 13, I was able to use web components generated via StencilJS as per the [with-stencil](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/881d202962b4226330b6fe4986d0cc943e4f40e6/examples/with-stencil) starter, by defining the custom elements in _app.tsx.

```
import { useLayoutEffect } from 'react'
import { applyPolyfills, defineCustomElements } from 'test-component/loader'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    applyPolyfills().then(() => {
      defineCustomElements(window)
    })
  }, [])
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

// Then use in any component like so
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <my-component first="Next.js" last="The React Framework"></my-component>
    </div>
  )
}
```

With the advent of default Server components, **is it even possible to use web components (which to my knowledge rely on browser APIs) in server components?**
I tried adapting my project by defining a `CustomElements` client component containing the above `defineCustomElements`, then importing that into a page.tsx server component,

```
'use client';
import { useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import { applyPolyfills, defineCustomElements } from 'path/to/your/stencil-components/loader';


const CustomElements = () => {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    applyPolyfills().then(() => {
      defineCustomElements(window)
    })
  }, [])
  return <></>;
}

export default CustomElements;
```

but the web components don't render and I get errors like

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$hostElement$')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$instanceValues$')
```

from the web component library.

Any ideas?

Comment: This `defineCustomElements` remind of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75951134/next-js-app-folder-is-there-some-entry-point-a-direct-replacement-for-app-t/75963374. Check the answer there. Maybe it would help.

Comment: @YoussoufOumar yea as mentioned I tried that approach. That's where I get the errors. I've updated my example with the CustomElements component.

Comment: I actually am not sure if that's the same question as mine - this actually looks like an error coming from the web component library. Or where actually is the error thrown?

Comment: Any solution? I'm blocked with the same problem