# How to Correctly Place _app.tsx in a Next.js Project for Custom App Configuration?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm working on a Next.js project and trying to implement custom app configuration as outlined in the Next.js documentation regarding _app.tsx. However, I've encountered some confusion and issues regarding where to place the _app.tsx file and how to structure the directories properly.

According to the documentation, _app.tsx is used for initializing pages and allows for the customization of global page behaviors. I understand it should somehow be related to or placed within a pages directory, but the exact placement and setup process isn't clear to me. Here's what I've tried:

Placing a page folder inside an app folder, which resulted in an error.
Placing the page folder outside of the app folder, which also led to an error.
Putting _app.tsx directly in the app folder, and then outside of the app folder, both attempts still resulted in errors.
Moreover, I'm facing a specific error related to my authentication context when trying to run my project:

#### The error message:

```
 ⨯ Error: useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider
    at useAuth (./context/AuthProvider.tsx:20:15)
    at Page (./app/signup/page.tsx:24:96)
  14 |     const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  15 |     if (!context) {
> 16 |         throw new Error('useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider');
     |              ^
  17 |     }
  18 |     return context;
  19 | };
```

#### The content of inside of the _app.tsx file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NextUIProvider } from '@nextui-org/react';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { AuthProvider } from '@/context/AuthProvider';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    return (
        <NextUIProvider>
            <AuthProvider>
                {/* NAV WILL GO HERE */}
                <Component {...pageProps} />
                {/* FOOTER WILL GO HERE */}
            </AuthProvider>
        </NextUIProvider>
    );
}

export default MyApp;
```

This error persists regardless of where I place _app.tsx. It's unclear to me if the placement of _app.tsx is influencing this error, or if there's a different issue at play related to how I'm using my AuthProvider and useAuth hook.

Could someone clarify the correct placement and setup for _app.tsx in a Next.js project and offer insights into why I might be encountering the above error related to useAuth and AuthProvider?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

What I've Tried:

- Moving the _app.tsx file into a pages folder and placing it inside of the app folder, which resulted in an error.
- Placing the pages folder (containing _app.tsx) outside of the app folder, which also led to an error.
- Putting _app.tsx directly in the root of the app folder, and also trying it outside of the app folder. Both attempts resulted in errors.

Despite these attempts, I'm consistently facing an error related to the use of my useAuth hook.

Answer (score 0):

[`_app.js`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/custom-app) should be in the `pages` folder (`pages/_app.js`). But you seem to have both the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) and the [`pages`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) routers at the same time. I guess you created your project to use the `app` router, as you have said yes to the last answer of the CLI shown below:

[image]

If so, and you want the `pages` router, you may want to restart and say no or delete the `app` folder manually, because having both will very likely lead to more and more conflicts.

The `_app.js` does not exist within the context of the `app` router. [The equivalent of `_app.js` is `app/layout.js`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75951134/next-js-app-folder-is-there-some-entry-point-a-direct-replacement-for-app-t)